# Pyside eventFilter and handling the case of None or missing attributes

Tags: python, pyside

I have a eventFilter in place for my Label class, which works but it gives an error when there are no required attributes in place.

How Should I check when and if the attributes are there? For example in this case:
Event.Buttons().

```
self.installEventFilter(self)

# Handles mouse events
def eventFilter(self, object, event):
    if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
        print ('QtGui.QCursor.pos()')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for the presence of the `buttons` attribute by using [`hasattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr) like

```
if hasattr(event, "buttons"):
  if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
    print ('QtGui.QCursor.pos()')
```

A more "pythonic" approach would be by catching the exception like

```
try:
  if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
    print ('QtGui.QCursor.pos()')
except AttributeError:
  pass # Or do something about it
```

Note that `hasattr` is also implemented that way internally, i.e. it tries to call `getattr` and returns `False` if an exception was thrown.

Comment: Thank you for a very swift answer. This is probably off-topic but how should I handle if eventFilter returns "NoneType"? :)